# "Was kostet..." vs. "Wie viel kostet..." vs. "Wieviel kostet..."

Tags: difference, interrogative

I’ve seen these examples:

> Was kostet eine Fahrkarte nach …?
>
> Wie viel kostet es bis zum/zur/nach …?
>
> Wieviel kostet ein Einzelzimmer/Doppelzimmer?

In all cases the interrogative translates to *how much*. What is the difference (if any) between their meanings in each phrase, or are there any other differences?

Answer (score 9):

First of all: Since the German orthography reform of 1996 "wieviel" is out of the question. You will find it in older texts, but since then you have to write it as "wie viel".

So it's *was kostet* versus *wie viel kostet*.

Fortunately, when asking for a price, there is nearly no difference and you can use both interchangeably 99 % of the time, but in everyday language it is more common to say "was kostet".

What are the differences?

> Wie viel kostet – required amount
>
> Was kostet – type of consideration

---

"Wie viel" always asks for a specific amount, e.g.,

> Wie viel kostet die Fahrkarte? – 3,50 €
>
> Wie viel kostet uns die Umweltverschmutzung? – xxx Milliarden Euro pro Jahr.
>
> Wie viel kostet uns die Umweltverschmutzung? – xxx Tote pro Jahr.

---

"Was kostet" may ask for *everything* and can be used for more abstract questions, e.g.,

> Was kostet die Fahrkarte? – 3,50 €.
>
> Was kostet ein Pakt mit dem Teufel? – Deine Seele.
>
> Was kostet uns die Umweltverschmutzung? – xxx Milliarden Euro pro Jahr.
>
> Was kostet uns die Umweltverschmutzung? – Unsere Gesundheit.

Comment: I would say: if "wie viel" is asked, the unit seems to be clear, so "wie viel kostet die Fahrkarte" could be answered "3,50" instead of "3,50 €". As you point out "was kostet" is everyday common language, the "3,50" is used here and for everyday do fit much better here - language loves its inconsistencies^^

Answer (score 2):

The semantic difference between **"Was kostet ..."** and **"Wieviel kostet ..."** 
is, although probably unreflected by the persons that use it, that the first one could be answered by e.g. "Sie kostet Geld" while the latter aims towards a more quantitative reply.

Comment: Welcome to German SE. Insulting someone that is posting a question is out of scope of this site. Please consider editing your answer to keep only the part that is relevant for the question.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: I fail to see how this insults the asker (or anybody else). “unreflected by those posting these questions” is referring to those using “wie viel”, “was kostet”, etc.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it says clearly *posting* not *using* or *asking*  these questions. I flagged this answer as rude but the flag was declined.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: my understanding of the here posted answer does not refer to "the people of the context that want to know the price" - because these people are unmentioned/ no context is given. So if I would cut anything I find insulting, the result: "...difference between ... is, that the first one could be answered by e.g...."

Comment: I edited the answer, because I felt like the way it was expressed, was indeed insulting towards the person who asked the question. I hope, my change still repressents your meaning @duc_, if not feel free to edit your answer again or roll back my edit.

Comment: @Iris: as was said by Wrzlprmft the answer was not about the question asked by Aaron, it was about people who ask questions (note the plural in the original version!) like those given as an example (*Was..., Wie viel, ... Wie viel*). Those people might indeed be unaware (or "unreflected") of any differences when using (or "posting") the given variants. So I can not see any offensive behaviour here either.

Comment: @Takkat Maybe. How do you know? At least 3 ppl. don't see it this way. Why do you defend a poorly written answer instead of letting OP clarify?

Comment: @Takkat, I interpreted the plural as the gender neutral "they". And I prefered to edit the question, instead of downvoting it.

Comment: @Iris your edit is just fine as it takes out much of the heat that this misunderstanding unfortunately created. Thank you for this. They can be gender neutral but this would not lead to a plural for "question".

Comment: @Olafant: sure, the OP would have to tell us. If you really want them to come back you'd need to be more welcoming. Also please consider that the OP may not speak German or English as their native language. From what I can see here  the answer was clear and helpful and it is even more so after the edit. Any downvotes are no longer justified here.

Comment: Obviously _posting_ in the original phrasing of the answer was supposed to carry the meaning of `[Fragen] stellen` (`asking [questions]`), namely asking either one of both variants. The author assumed that most people would treat both variants the same and expressed that in a syntactically correct way. It's bad enough imho that the new CoC encourages the Verbal Police, but at the very least that policing should be based on understanding of the language. PS: Apologies to anybody who feels offended by this comment. While I did not check my wording for CoC-compliance, no such effect was intended.